# Read Offers Avis

Tags: c#, pdf

I'm trying to read a Offers Avis from a Danish super market, but without luck. It's a flash file like this http://www.foetex.dk/ugenstilbud/Pages/Zmags.aspx.
I discovered that you can download the Offers Avis as PDF, and after that I've tried several days to read the pdf to something useful, but i'm not really getting anything.

Here's my code, and the pdf im reading
https://www.dropbox.com/s/o7uhfanu459n18f/input.pdf

```
    public static string ReadPdfFile(string fileName)
    {
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);
            ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
            for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {

                string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);

                currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
                text.Append(currentText);
            }
            pdfReader.Close();
        }
        return text.ToString();
    }
```

As i said, it's not really useful, because the prices aren't always matching the product above. If anyone have any structured why to read a pdf like that please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to find a structured way to read the information because the information is not really presented in a structured way.

That being said there are some hints in the content stream that might help if you are ready to build your own custom text extraction strategy.

iText(Sharp) comes with two default text extraction strategies, the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` you use and the `LocationTextExtractionStrategy.` The "simple" strategy does not make any assumptions on the page layout but assumes the text segments in the page content stream to be in reading order already and, therefore, does not try to re-arrange them. The "location" strategy assumes a single column multiline page layout but does not assume the text segments in the page content stream to be in reading order and, therefore, re-arranges them by their coordinates matching the assumed layout.

Your [sample PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o7uhfanu459n18f/input.pdf) actually requires yet a different type of strategy which is somewhat an inbetween. The text segments in its text objects (bracketed as "**BT** ... **ET**" in the content stream) belong together and come in reading order, but text objects following each other are not necessarily in reading order.

E.g. "Santiago 1541 75 cl. Chile. Cabernet Sauvignon eller Chardonnay. føtex normalpris 48.95 Pr. liter 40.-", "Frit valg", "30.-", "Spar 1895" are text objects following each other but "Langelænder pølser 450-500 g. Flere varianter. Pr. kg max. 40.-", "Frit valg", "18.-", and "Det er" are text objects not following each other immediately. (Furthermore "Billigt" is not even text but instead drawn using path and fill commands.)

Therefore, the kind of text extraction strategy you need should collect text segments (reported to the strategy's `RenderText` method) between the start and the end of a text object (reported to the methods `BeginTextBlock` and `EndTextBlock` respectively) in a way similar to the approach of the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` but it should also collect coordinate data (also reported to the `RenderText` method) to determine the rectangle encompassing the text object.

Afterwards it should sort these text object contents by their encompassing rectangles (text objects with rectangles near to each other's most likely belonging together).

As some words, especially the "Billigt" occurances, are not present as text in the PDF but as a vector image, those will not be found, but the essential product and price informations most likely can be found like that.

I'm not sure, though, whether or not implementing that strategy is worth the time because the structure found can change anytime if fotex change their PDF creation software.

PS: When collecting the text contents of a text objects, you might also want to keep an eye on font sizes. Otherwise you'll merely get "Spar 1895" when parsing

[image: Spar 1895]

PPS: For in-depth information on text in PDFs consult the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), chapter 9 *Text.*